# Downloads and C drive(O.S)

Tags: windows-10

Does free space in c-drive matter when I am downloading huge file to another drive(other than C). The case is I have is downloading a 200gb backup with  about 2gb in c drive and the drive I am downloading it to has 1tb.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally there will not be a problem for a straight download.

But if you are downloading a torrent,
some torrent clients download to a temporary folder and then copy it to the
target folder.
So it all depends on your download program.

For a straight download from a web address, I would recommend using a download manager
that has a resume option, so if the download stops for any reason you don't
have to restart from zero.

Comment: In theory, the web browser's built-in resume should be sufficient. (It is after all using the same HTTP byte-range feature that download managers do.)

Comment: @grawity: Yes, in theory, but I have seen cases that didn't (Firefox).

Comment: It ain't a torrent, its a backup, a huge tar file. And unfortunately firefox resume doesn't work on it either.

Answer (score 1):

There won't be problem as long as your other drive has disk space for the new data.

Answer (score 1):

I have had this exact problem too with massive downloads.

Chrome and some other browsers do temporarily cache very large downloads onto the C drive, even if your download destination is to another drive.

Downloading a large TAR file is likely to freeze or even crash your PC if the available space fills up during the download, and it runs out of resources. If you look in task manager you will see when it's getting close though.

My solution for PCs regularly downloading massive files was to replace the C drive with a larger one, ie more free space which solved the issue.